# Emulator stops working when sending or receiving sms

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I'm trying to send sms from one emulator to another. Every time I send the sms, the emulator stops working and I get the message "emulator64-arm quit unexpectedly". I also used the terminal to send sms to the emulator and the same thing happens, the emulator would quit.

I wonder if anyone's had such a problem or know how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try GenyMotion emulator at first，it's  much better.